# Apache Alias multiple sites on vps

Tags: laravel, apache

I am running multiple Laravel sites on the same VPS (IP-based, no domain).
It all works through using this in the Apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Alias /site1 "/var/www/site1/public"
        <Directory "/var/www/site1/public">
                Allowoverride All
        </Directory>
        Alias /site2 "/var/www/site2/public"
        <Directory "/var/www/site2/public">
                Allowoverride All
        </Directory>
```

And then each site has its own vhost.conf file such as:

site1.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site1/public/
        ServerName site1
</VirtualHost>
```

This works perfect so that when I go to [IP address]/site1 and [IP address]/site2 I am redirected correctly by Apache.

The main issue is that when I move the code from my local machine to the VPS all absolute links i.e. css and js that start with a trailing slash / point to the root of the server and not to the site's root.

Is there a way by .htaccess or through Apache configuration that each site can have a relative root of its own? I have tried the base tag but it's not good enough and I am thinking I may be missing Apache expertise to know how to properly do this. I have tried Location and LocationMatch with no success.

I am trying to avoid going through each one of the url references and adding siteX/css, siteX/js, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set your `APP_URL` to include the subdirectory in youur `.env`

```
`APP_URL=https://example.com/site1`
```

Now use the `asset()` helper to load your assets

```
asset('css/site.css');
```

The `asset` helper will prepend the following to the string argument passed into it:

```
http://example.com/site1/assets/css/site.css
```